# Including meta-java layer to Yocto causes parse failure

Tags: java, linux, yocto

I am trying to include meta-java with yocto build:

I am using raspberry pi 3 b+ with a 64-bit compiler

> `MACHINE = "raspberrypi3-64"`

I also added the following line to local.conf and added the layer path in bblayer.conf

> `IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " openjdk-14"`

But when i invoke bitbake like so:

> `bitbake openjdk-14`

I am getting a parse error:
*bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable LLVM_CONFIGURE_ARCH*

Need help in solving this error.  Can anyone point me to the correct course of action?

Comment: Please add more information as to which Yocto version and which version of meta-java you are using.

Comment: @sob I am using the yocto Version 3.1.1,  yocto branch dunfell and meta-java branch dunfell

Answer (score 0):

It seems openjdk-14 is not yet supported. I have the same configuration as you, raspberrypi3-64 with dunfell:
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'openjdk-14'. Close matches:
openjdk-7
openjdk-8